# Why is a Gelman-Rubin diagnostic of < 1.1 considered acceptable?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, convergence, rstan

In multiple sources a Gelman-Rubin MCMC convergence diagnostic of less than 1.1 is considered evidence that chains have converged.

For example in this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54155673/is-there-a-function-check-rhat-in-rstan-package

I'm not clear why.

Answer (score 6):

Are you wondering how GR works, or why 1.1 seems to be the accepted cut-off. If the latter, you're not alone: [arXiv paper questioning 1.1 cutoff](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.09384) argues that 1.1 is too high. They also propose a revised version of GR that is improved and can even evaluate a single chain.

The Stan folks are also working on a [revised version of Stan's Rhat](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.08008), which I believe is GR.

So if you're questioning 1.1, your instincts seem to be good. If you're questioning GR, the proposed revisions may also support your instincts.

Comment: Thank you, it was the latter.